# arr.reduce и стрелочная функция

Tags: javascript, массивы

Что делает ",0" после колбэк функции и зачем он нужен?

```
console.log([3,2,1,4,5].reduce((a,b) => a+(b%2?1:0),0)); //output: 3; с ",0"

console.log([3,2,1,4,5].reduce((a,b) => a+(b%2?1:0))); //output: 5; без ",0"
```

Comment: RTFM https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce и стрелочность тут ни при чем

Comment: `arr.reduce(callback(accumulator, currentValue[, index[, array]]), [, initialValue])`. **initialValue** - *A value to use as the first argument to the first call of the callback. If no initialValue is supplied, the first element in the array will be used. Calling reduce() on an empty array without an initialValue will throw a TypeError.*

Answer (score 0):

в вашем случае 0 после колбэк функции - это начальное значение a . Для удобства заменим (a,b) на (accumulator, value). Итак, 0 это начальное значение accumulator.  Происходит следующее: если value % 2 приводится к true (результат остатка от деления не равен 0), то accumulator увеличивается на еденицу, иначе (если приводится к false, т.е. value % 2 === 0)  увеличивается на нуль (т.е. не изменяется).
true нам дадут числа 3, 1, 5 а это значит, что условие увеличения сработает три раза.
Теперь, если начальное значение accumulator это 0 , то получим 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 3.
Если мы НЕ указали начальное значение явно, то будет использован первый элемент и мы получим 3 + 1 + 1 = 5; В этом случае НЕ важно чему равен остаток от деления на 2 первого элемента. Например Если значение 1го элемента было бы не 3 а 4. То получим результат 4 + 1 + 1 = 6.